# how to move teeth with mouth shapekey

Tags: shape-keys

The mouth movement is controlled by shapekey.
But the teeth has no movement.
How can I make the teeth move with the mouth?
Please find attached snapshot.
[image: attached, teeth not move with mouth]

Comment: Can not share the file as it is about 1GB. The teeth is separate mesh, while the face is another. The face has shape key, can smile etc. is it clear?

Comment: my idea is to (1) make an empty object move with the mouth together, and then (2) let the teeth copy the movement of the empty object. I know how to do (2), but I don't how to do (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create an empty
2. right click on the empties z location -> copy as new driver
3. right click on your shape keys value -> paste driver

change to "scripted expression"

[image]

now you can move your empty on z-location from 0 to 1 and the mouth should open and close

[image]

4. repeat step 2
5. paste driver on your z-location of your upper teeth, change to scripted expression
6. do the same for lower teeth
7. depending on your teeth location adapt the formula for your tooth, mine worked with this:

[image]

result:

[image]

of course you should finetune the movement in the drivers editor.

[image]

Comment: Very good idea. But the first step should be opposite. Not make the empty object control/drive the mouth, but make the mouth (which is driven by shape key) drive the empty object. How to make it?   looks like the "scripted expression" can help.

Comment: I understand your point, it can solve the problem.